# iPhone SQLite date problem

Tags: iphone, sqlite, date

Database gets created just fine, and the insert works just fine. I'm having problem with the select statement below. It returns no records and no error. A select on any other field works just fine. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
"create table if not exists data (pkey integer primary key, doc date)"

[db executeUpdate:@"insert into data ( doc) values (?)" , [NSDate date]];

"select * FROM data WHERE doc between '2009-08-23' and '2009-08-23' "
```

Comment: I am trying to access using FMDatabase, but I am entering records using a GUI, each time I do not get any records. please check my question and suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772601/date-entry-into-database-through-gui-for-date-which-is-readable-by-fmdatabase

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The part `between '2009-08-23' and '2009-08-23'` is always false, because that's a range of zero time, for lack of a better description.

If you want items occurring on exactly 2009-08-23, select `between '2009-08-23' and '2009-08-24'` which will range from midnight on the 23rd to midnight on the 24th.

Here's an example of this in action:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE t (d DATETIME);
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('now');
2009-08-24 02:32:20
sqlite> INSERT INTO t VALUES (datetime('now'));
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t;
2009-08-24 02:33:42
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t where d BETWEEN '2009-08-24' and '2009-08-24';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM t where d BETWEEN '2009-08-24' and '2009-08-25';
2009-08-24 02:33:42
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had to do this exact type of lookup on sqlite and here is a simple date formatting example to get the start and end of day timestamps for your date.

In my case I am storing the timestamps with this timestamp format in sqlite: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS".  This example uses the current date ([NSDate date]).

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *startOfDay = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];  
// add a full day and subtract 1 second to get the end of day timestamp
NSDate *endOfDay = [startOfDay addTimeInterval:(60*60*24)-1];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"];
```

You can then use startOfDay and endOfDay for your query values.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does string comparison, not date comparison.

So, one way to solve your problem is:

"select * FROM data WHERE doc between '2009-08-23' and '2009-08-23 99' "